# Map JAXB generated Objects using XPATH

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to map the value using Xpath instead of directly accessing the Classname.methodname Using JAXB

eg:

Customer/name

ideal jaxb :  new Customer().setName("XXXX");

instead of above : xxxx.setValue("customer/name","XXXXX") should automatically set the value for the Xpath. and generate in the XML .

Is there any provision like this in JAXB. ( I know this in castor using FieldDescriptors and ClassDescriptors).

Answer (score 0):

As far I know there is no provison in JAXB to do this. It's primary purpose is to

Marshall and Unmarshall XML Documents to/from Java Objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, JAXB is irrelevanto to what you want to do; if you can handle the expressions not being XPATH,  have a look into Apache Beanutils: specifically `BeanUtils.setProperty(object, "customer.name", "XXXX")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wiling to use another technology, JXPath can be used to navigate javabeans via something similar to xpaths. You can also use JXPath to poplulate javabeans with information 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

Specifically, when you supply a factory you can create objects. There are several situations that are not supported nativly, but with a little bit of thought you can implement your own extension of createPathAndSetValue that can deal with your specific predicate logic.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/users-guide.html#Creating_Objects